# copy folder structure without .svn folders

Tags: svn, windows-7, powershell

Could someone help me with the script for copying all folders from project structure without .svn folders ? Thanks for any help

Comment: Why don't you just export it from SVN as that takes it out of the repo without the metadata?

Comment: +1 Expo from repo. You can use the command-line svn to do so also.

Answer (score 5):

You simply need `exclude` do you?

```
copy-item $source -destination $dest -exclude *.svn -recurse
```

Comment: Seems logical, but doesn't work for me. As @RhysC says, check out [Exclude list in Powershell Copy-Item does not appear to be working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731752/exclude-list-in-powershell-copy-item-does-not-appear-to-be-working])

Answer (score 3):

that doesnt seem to work (at least on my machines). See : [Exclude list in PowerShell Copy-Item does not appear to be working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731752/exclude-list-in-powershell-copy-item-does-not-appear-to-be-working)
for a solution that works for me (swap out the exlcudes obviously)

Comment: It doesn't work for me either. If there are sub-directories in $source then the .svn folder inside those sub-directories will be copied.