# Powershell exclude recursively

Tags: powershell

I seem to be having trouble with exclusions and copying directories recursively in powershell.

I want to copy a directory recursively, but have it include any file that matches `test.txt`.

My Source directory looks like this

- Root

  - test.txt
  - test.ps1
  - testDir

    - test.txt
    - test.ps1

Running the command below results with the following output. Where it copies excludes the first instance of test.txt, but not the second. What am I missing?

- Copied Root

  - test.ps1
  - testDir

    - test.txt
    - test.ps1

My Script:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .\TestDir -Recurse -Exclude test.txt | Copy-Item -Destination .\temporary -Recurse -Exclude text.txt
```

Comment: `robocopy .\testDir .\temporary /XF test.txt /s`

Comment: You seem to have a typo in the `Copy-Item` statement, the `Exclude` entry is spelled te**x**t.txt, instead of te**s**t.txt. So when `testDir` gets copied, all child items are copied too (since text.txt doesn't exist)

Comment: I appreciate your attention to detail, unfortunately it is a red herring caused by my speedy typing, and a lack of attention to detail. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confess, I [Nerd Sniped](https://xkcd.com/356/) myself into doing this, with a 'well that can't be hard...'

The problem appears to be that if copy-item gets the slightest whiff of a directory it just copies the whole thing without any consideration of what's inside it, completely ignoring any concept of filtering along the way!

While trying to solve the filtering problem I stumbled upon [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731752/exclude-list-in-powershell-copy-item-does-not-appear-to-be-working) -

Your solution appears to be something like this -

```
$source = "E:\PS\test-output\test"
$dest = "E:\PS\test-output\test1"
$exclude = @('test.txt') 
Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse -Exclude $exclude `
    | Copy-Item -Destination {Join-Path $dest $_.FullName.Substring($source.length)}
```

This ditches copy-item's (seemingly braindead) recursion and builds your own.

Comment: Yes! Ok So confession time. I came across that answer myself but kept having trouble because I was doing this in a script I was creating. So I was passing in relative paths, so E:\PS\Test-output\test was just .\test. When the Sub-string was called on that some strange results happened. So for some reason you putting it this way I was able to get it through my thick skull. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: Thank you for the nerd snipe ;) - I actually think it is a bug in copy-item I can't see how it could be expected behaviour.