# usage of xcopy command in octopus deploy PostDeploy.ps1

Tags: powershell, command-line, octopus-deploy

I'm trying to copy files using xcopy in octopus deploy. But seems xcopy is not working. Here is the command I'm using in PostDeploy.ps1

```
xcopy Content C:\websitecode /e /y /exclude:test.txt
```

Reason for using xcopy is I can exclude multiple files.

Can someone please help me how to use xcopy in octopus deploy...

Thank you.

Comment: What, exactly, does `xcopy is not working` mean? No files copied? Wrong files copied? Right files copied into wrong directory? Something else unexpected behavior?

Comment: Hi VonPryz, Thanks for your reply. In my case, xcopy is not copying the files and I don't see any error.

Comment: What is in the text.txt file?

Comment: You can use Powershells copy-item to exclude multiple items by piping get-childitem into copy-item as pointed out in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731752/exclude-list-in-powershell-copy-item-does-not-appear-to-be-working). Therefore you don't have to use xcopy to achieve what you want.

Comment: @tobre
Yes. that will work. Thank you tobre.

Answer (score 0):

Could you see that your postdeploy.ps1 execution has started in your octopus deployment task log? If you could see try my favorite xcopy script which I am already using it.

```
$FullPath = "C:\MyFolder"

if ($OctopusEnvironmentName -ceq 'Development')

{
  Write-Host "Console app will be execute"

  & "xcopy" $FullPath/myfolder/*.dll "c:\targetfolder" your parameters | Write-Host

  Write-Host "Console app execution has finied"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue that Octopus silently eats `xcopy`, and the Octopus folks [don't seem too concerned about it](https://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/problems/43575-xcopy-is-not-working-in-octopus-deploy), providing tons of workarounds like "just use `copy-item`". That mostly works for me, but I wish I understood why xcopy doesn't work because it might be the case that other things fail silently as well.