# powershell copy all folder structure and exclude one or more folders

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use PowerShell to copy a folder with sub-folders from our users to a small backup. These folders contain a folder called "windows" I don't want to copy.

I have tried "exclude" but can't seem to get it to work. 
This is the script so far:

```
Copy-Item "E:\Curos folder" -Exclude 'Windows' -Destination "E:\Curos folder backup" -Recurse -Verbose
```

I have read other posts but don't quiet understand how it works

It's my first time working with PowerShell

Comment: "can't seem to get it to work" <- what's happening? Are you getting errors/are the files copying at all/etc?

Comment: This might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731752/exclude-list-in-powershell-copy-item-does-not-appear-to-be-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are complete right.
Actually the script it's simpler than the one I have wrote before.
Here we go:

```
$source =  "C:\Users\gaston.gonzalez\Documents\02_Scripts"
$destination = "D:\To Delete"

$exclude = "Windows"
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $source | Where {($_.PSIsContainer) -and ($exclude -notcontains $_.Name)}


foreach ($f in $folders){ 
      Write-Host "This folders will be copied: $f"
      Copy-Item -Path $source\$f -Destination $destination\$f -Recurse -Force
}
```

Comment: Hello Tuertolin 

It works some what it copis to test folders i have in af test environment and then makes the same folder again as another subfolder like this. Curos_folder\Test1\Test1.

and it only takes the dokuments in the 2 folders under the mail folder: E:\Curos_folder.

Also can you explain how Param works? i like to use it more in the future.

as i said im new and im going to ask alot of questions if you don't mind?

But thank you so much so far.

Comment: Hi @Mikkel, I have edited my answer for you.
And below you will find the explanation for Param
Is not necessary to use it at the beginning but when your scripts gets more and more complex it's good idea to use it.   

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554301.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem $root -Directory -Recurse | % {$_.name -ne 'Windows'} | foreach {Copy-Item "$($_.FullName)" -Destination $dest -Recurse}
```

I haven't tested it but it's the skeleton of something you should be able to make work, although I don't find the point of using recurse on both, Get-ChildItem and Copy-Item my advice is to use it on Get-ChildItem.

Comment: Can you explain how im suppose to use it?